# SELECT first value from 3 tables that is not null

Tags: oracle

Having 3 tables with name(varcahr) value(varchar) pairs how do I select the value for a given name from one of the table with respect to the following conditions

1. select value from tab_1 if it exists for name else select it from tab_2 if it exists in tab_2 else from tab_3
2. do it in one giant select if possible

Comment: Any id column?or in other words can you JOIN them without a cartesian product?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are couple ways of get what you want. From the top of my head I can think about version with `UNION`, `FULL JOIN`, and `LEFT JOIN`. The latter seems to me as most preferable from readability and performance point of view :

```
SELECT NVL(t1.value,NVL(t2.value,t3.value)) as value
-- Or use coalesce instead of NVLs :
--SELECT COALESCE(t1.value,t2.value,t3.value) as value
FROM
(SELECT 'name_to_search' as name FROM DUAL)a
LEFT JOIN table1 t1 ON (t1.name= a.name)
LEFT JOIN table1 t2 ON (t2.name= a.name)
LEFT JOIN table1 t3 ON (t3.name= a.name)
```

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
SELECT
  CASE 
  WHEN (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table1 WHERE name='name_you_want' AND value IS NOT NULL)>0
  THEN (SELECT value FROM table1 WHERE name='name_you_want')
  WHEN (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table2 WHERE name='name_you_want' AND value IS NOT NULL)>0
  THEN (SELECT value FROM table2 WHERE name='name_you_want')
  ELSE (SELECT value FROM table3 WHERE name='name_you_want')
 END AS value FROM DUAL
```

Here's a [fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/575f5/27)